# How can I read the MANIFEST.MF file during the test execution?

Tags: java, maven, manifest

I am trying to automate acceptance test using TestLink, Cucumber, Jenkins and Maven. To do that, I am asking to read the MANIFEST.MF file created by Maven. I have to do it during the test execution.

I found out this example of code :

```
`public static String readVersion() throws IOException {
InputStream in = VersionUtil.class.getResourceAsStream("/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");
Manifest manifest = new Manifest(in);
// Lire la propriété "Implementation-Version" du Manifest
String version = manifest.getMainAttributes().getValue(Attributes.Name.IMPLEMENTATION_VERSION);
return version;
}`
```

But I am getting a NullPointerException when trying to execute it... Do you have any idea why ?

I am launching Maven with the simple command : mvn package test.

I think the problem comes from the moment when this code is launching, I should launch it after the package phase, is there any way to do that ?

Thank you !

Comment: Do you already have a manifest file in your project, or is it entirely written by Maven?

Comment: It is entirely written by Maven

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try the code below, since most classloader can be cast to URLClassLoader

```
URLClassLoader cl = (URLClassLoader) getClass().getClassLoader();
try {
  URL url = cl.findResource("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");
  Manifest manifest = new Manifest(url.openStream());
  ...
 } catch (IOException E) {
  // handle
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, I just tried it but still get Null Pointer Exception at the call of my method...